# CSS syntax highlighting in VSCode: @layer keyword support

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you might know some browsers already support CSS Cascade Layers (https://caniuse.com/?search=%40layer). The main keyword of this feature is @layer. Unfortunately VSCode displays a warning message:

```
Unknown at rule @layer css(unknownAtRules)
```

[image]

Is there any list of css keywords to include @layer keyword in my VSCode settings?

I tried to use the "css.customData" option. But I didn't manage to get any results. I created a css-data.json file in the same folder as the settings.json file.

What the correct path to the file should look like? I would like to have a relative path but I tried an absolute path as well. Nothing happened. I'm using portable VSCode if it is matter. Here are my attempts:

```
"css.customData": ["c:\\app\\VSCode\\data\\user-data\\User\\css-data.json"],
"css.customData": ["css-data.json"],
"css.customData": [".\\data\\user-data\\User\\css-data.json"],
"css.customData": ["./data/user-data/User/css-data.json"],
```

Here is a content of css-data.json:

```
{
    "version": 1.0,
    "properties": [],
    "atDirectives": [
        {
            "name": "@layer",
            "description": "Declares a cascade layer."
        }
    ],
    "pseudoClasses": [],
    "pseudoElements": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to use

```
"css.customData": [".vs-code/css-data.json"]
```

but in case that doesn't work; I fixed this for myself in the following way:

in: .vscode/settings.json

```
"css.customData": [".vscode/css_custom_data.json"]
```

and then the .vscode/css_custom_data.json file itself:

```
{
    "atDirectives": [
      {
        "name": "@layer",
        "description": "The @layer CSS at-rule is used to declare a cascade layer and can also used to define the order of precedence in case of multiple cascade layers.",
        "references": [
                {
                    "name": "@layer",
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This however fails to fully permit the use of the @layer spec as @import rules still can't include a layer() as an example:

```
@layer reset, pallet, base, layout, local;
@import "style/reset.css"   layer(reset);      /* unifies / css reset */
@import "style/pallet.css"  layer(pallet);     /* color pallets */
@import "style/main.css"    layer(base);       /* primary css*/
```

now throws 3 errors and 0 warnings whereas without this fix it also throws a warning.

Comment: thank you for your response but unfortunately it does not work for for me, I'm using portable VS Code (with data folder) and I don't know how to provide correct path to css_custom_data.json file

Answer (score 2):

`@layer` and `@property` will be supported in vscode v1.72 - due out early October, 2022.

See [1.72 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#css--less--scss):

> The CSS language support now also understands the **@property** and
> **@layer** at-rules.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is just a rule that hasn't been updated in the VSCode internal CSS linters.

Hunting for this warning I came across this [stylelint issue #6084 ([at-rule-no-unknown] incorrectly flags @layer)](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/6084). They fixed this through a [PR in May 2022](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/pull/6093).

I was assuming that stylelint is the underlying CSS linter for VS Code but appears it isn't. You can install the [stylelint vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint) (and disable the internal VSCode CSS linters) and this `@layer` error goes away.

[image]